# Enabling Swift compiler optimization causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash in custom view controller transition

Tags: swift, uikit, exc-bad-access, compiler-optimization, transition

For replacing the default animation when pushing / popping a view controller onto the navigation stack with a cross dissolve animation I have implemented a custom view controller transition that conforms to the protocol [`UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontrolleranimatedtransitioning).

Here's my implementation of the animation function:

```
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

    guard let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from),
        let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to) else {
        return
    }

    let animationView = transitionContext.containerView
    animationView.addSubview(toViewController.view) // 
    let duration = transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)

    fade(from: fromViewController.view, 
         to: toViewController.view, 
         duration: duration, 
         completion: {
        let didComplete = !transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled
        transitionContext.completeTransition(didComplete)
    })
}
```

When running the app with my *Debug* configuration in works like a charm. However, when running it with my *Release* configuration it crashes in the line marked with .

The difference that causes the crash is the **Swift compiler optimization level** which is defined as follows:

- **Debug:** *None* [-Onone]
- **Release:** *Fast, Whole Module Optimization* [-O -whole-module-optimization]

I really think that the whole module optimization is a pretty good idea for our release. But I don't see which variable could possibly be released here and using `print` statements I've even checked that all those variables used in this line are properly set, i.e. the `animationView` and the `toViewController.view`. So what on earth is going on here? **What is the "optimization" that causes the crash?**

Comment: The cause of the crash doesn't seem to be within the snipped you posted. Everythings seems fine there and the works for me in a sample project. Is it possible to add more code to the question? Can you isolate the issue in a sample project?

Comment: I have in fact created a new sample project in which I only added my implementation of the `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` protocol and in that project everything works as expected under "Fast, Whole Module Optimization". So you're right that the cause for the crash must lie somewhere else. However, if I were to post more code here I just wouldn't know _which_ code. The lines I posted above are the only code directly linked to the problem. Other than that it's really just pushing a view controller using a regular segue. The same thing that _does_ work in the sample project...

Comment: When I enable the swift optimization at any level, my app crashes like crazy. Do you have a mixed objc -> swift project ?

Comment: Just had the same but in another context. Adding printing a variable that causes a crash did the fix for WMO builds LOL (that is just added print(variable) before its using)